# replace a returned property with another property from a different model linking by Id

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0

Hi I'm not quite sure how to do this.

I have this .NetCore EntityFrame controller that gets a list of characters.

It works when I simply get the list of characters by doing this:

```
return await _context.Character.ToListAsync();
```

This returns the name, class, race, age,  armorPoints, hitPoints, and spiritAnimalId for each character in the database.

But now, instead of simply returning just the spiritAnimalId, I want to return the actual name of the animal.

So I started writing some code, but quickly lost the ability to figure out how to return the name of the spirit animal.

Here is what I have:

```
    // GET: api/Characters
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Character>>> GetCharacters()
    {

        var characters= await _context.Character.ToListAsync();

        foreach(Character c in characters)
        {
            var a = _context.SpiritAnimal.FindAsync(c.spiritAnimalId);
            var name = a.Result.Name;
        }
        return charcters;
    }
```

So I'm lost as to how to return the list of projects and replace the spiritAnimalId with it's name.

NEW CODE:

```
    // GET: api/Characters
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<Character>>> GetCharacters()
    {
         var characters = await _context.Character
                       .Select(x => new
                       {
                           x.Id,
                           x.Name,
                           x.Race,
                           x.Class,
                           x.Age,
                           SpiritAnimalName = x.SpiritAnimalName.Name
                        })
                       .ToListAsync();

        return characters;
    }
```

NEW ERROR:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type
to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<System.Collections.Generic.List
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't already, you should have a navigation property on your `Character` class like:

```
public SpiritAnimal SpiritAnimal { get; set; }
```

Then, when you make your query, you should include this relationship, so it's joined in the same query:

```
var characters = await _context.Character.Include(x => x.SpiritAnimal).ToListAsync();
```

As you're iterating over the characters, you can simply access: `character.SpiritAnimal.Name`. If you're wanting to *only* return the name from the query, you'll need to use `Select` to project into another class or an anonymous object:

```
var characters = await _context.Character
    .Select(x => new
    {
        CharacterName = x.Name,
        SpiritAnimalName = x.SpiritAnimal.Name
    }
    .ToListAsync();
```

When the `Select` expression utilizes a property on a related entity, you don't need to explicitly load it; EF is smart enough to realize it needs to do a join to satisfy the return.

Comment: Hi thank you, so I tried that, and added all the Character properties and the spirtAnimalName, but for some reason, but I try to return 'characters', it is telling me that it Cannot implicitly convert type Generic.List to ActionResult. So would I need to create a new type?  Thanks

Comment: You're trying to return the list directly, when the return type is an ActionResult. If you're using an API controller in ASP.NET Core 2.1+ and the return type is the generic ActionResult<T>, then you can do that. But otherwise, or if the return type is IActionResult, then you must wrap it in a result, like via Ok(characters).

Comment: I am using netcore 3.1 and trying to return 'async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Character>>>' . So I should return an IEnumberable instead?  thanks

Comment: No. Your issue is covariance. The type param for ActionResult is invariant. Since you're telling it to expect IEnumerable, you'd have to actually return an IEnumerable, not just something that implements it, like List. However, there's no benefit to IEnumerable here, since it's already materialized. Just return Task<ActionResult<List<Character>>>

Comment: Hi Chris, I am returning the type that you reccomend, however, I am still getting the same error.  I have added the new code and new error to the question above.  Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to return anonymous types as some other type. What I gave you in my answer was for ease of explanation and since you didn't provide much information about the types you're working with. However, if you want to restructure the data like this, then you should really create a view model/DTO class, which you would then use to both project into via Select, and return.

Comment: Oh I see, so instead of ".Select(x => new" do something like ".Select new CharacterInfo"  Thank you!